# How can my css div with the display flex property be alignd to the right when it's wrapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a sort of gallery where all my user uploaded pictures get alignd in a div which holds one more divs which holds the picture. It will be more clear in the code ;) But the last item (the child div) aligns in the middle but I want the last      one to align to the left but I have tried now in hours to get this flex stuff to work and watched several tutorials on how the flex property behaves but no success :/

Here the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kra1b6LL/3/

```
#sWrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:10vh;
    height:75vh; /* Android Size */
    height:65vh; /* iPhone  Size */
    width:100%;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#sWrapperContent{
    background-color:blue;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#sStyleBox{
    border:1px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:23vh;
    width:18vh;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you just post a link to a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? + Don't give id (**#**) to multiple elements. *Id* is for a single element *Class* is for multiple.

Comment: good question, never did that hehe i'll try to edit it and insert a jsfiddle :) @Mihailo

Comment: Np, by using one of these two services you can expect to get answers much much faster then with raw code and screenshots. :)

Comment: alright :D It's updated now :) thanks for the tip ;) @Mihailo

Comment: use `justify-content: space-between`?

Comment: I tried that but this adds the 2 wrapped divs on both right and left when breaking the row :/ @kukkuz

Comment: so `justify-content: flex-start` effect is what you require? On a side note, you can't detect wrapping...

Comment: kind of but I still need them to be spread evenly over the whole row :/ @kukkuz

Comment: AFAIK and as far as I understand your problem, this is *not* possible as you can't detect wrapping *with CSS* and here the width of each flex item is dependent on viewport height (18vh) too - so I guess you will have to redesign with media queries and nested flexboxes...

Comment: I see, thanks @kukkuz :)

Comment: Maybe an invisible pseudo-element on the flex container? https://jsfiddle.net/kra1b6LL/4/

Comment: I've tried that @Michael_B but it's not perfect. As you can see the last row does not start where it should... I can't seem to fix that -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the justify-content style. Elements that won't fit on the first row, will break to the second, starting on the left side. To make the code more fancy i've added some margin to the child boxes.

https://jsfiddle.net/hyv4h4fy/

```css
#sWrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:10vh;
    height:75vh; /* Android Size */
    height:65vh; /* iPhone  Size */
    width:100%;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#sWrapperContent{
    background-color:blue;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
 
}

#sStyleBox{
    margin:5px;
    border:1px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:23vh;
    width:18vh;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sWrapper">
        <div id="sWrapperBeforeContent">
            <div id="sWrapperContent">


            <div id="sStyleBox">
                <div id="sStyleImg"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="sStyleBox">
                 <div id="sStyleImg"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="sStyleBox">
                <div id="sStyleImg"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="sStyleBox">
                <div id="sStyleImg"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="sStyleBox">
                <div id="sStyleImg"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="sStyleBox">
                <div id="sStyleImg"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="sStyleBox">
                <div id="sStyleImg"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="sStyleBox">
                <div id="sStyleImg"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="sStyleBox">
                <div id="sStyleImg"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="sStyleBox">
                <div id="sStyleImg"></div>
            </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```